# Are connect/write with OIO really asynchronous?

Tags: netty

I don't understand limitation point in OioClientSocketChannelFactory class.

It says: "A SocketChannel created by this factory does not support asynchronous operations. Any I/O requests such as "connect" and "write" will be performed in a blocking manner."

However SocketChannel is a Channel and therefore support only asynchronous operation.

Can someone clarify what exactly this mean because, in my opinion, these two descriptions contradict each other.

Regards,
Zarko

Answer (score 1):

OioClientSocketChannelFactory is just a layer above the usual java.io stuff. So everything is blocking in there. This means when you do a call which returns a ChannelFuture, it will be complete as soon as it get returned.

The cool thing about having the Oio.. and Nio.. impl share the same unified api is that you can flip between the two easily.